# Python EOF error on Mac OSX

Tags: python, unix

So I am a beginner in coding and I started learning Python a while back! Recently I was writing my own code. It's a translator project from english to pyg latin (Just a made up language adding 'ay' to the word. Now this is my code:

```
original = raw_input('Name any english word?')       

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():     #Testing if variable has characters and not numbers
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    if first == 'a'  or first == 'e' or first == 'i' or first == 'o' or first == 'u':
        new_word = word + pyg                    #Word translated to pyg latin
        print new_word
    else:
        new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + pyg
        print new_word
else:
    print "empty"                                #No word active
```

Problem is I keep getting a EOF error in my 3rd line? What is the problem and what is an EOF error?

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's valid Python.

Comment: Haha, I see you're using Codecademy to learn python ;). Good choice for beginning to learn python.

Comment: Did you copy/paste this code from elsewhere? It looks like you have some invisible character there.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs a bit more than some indent fixes, but I'll forgive. This works for me on OSx and PC.

```
original = raw_input('Name any english word?\n')
PYG = 'ay'
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():     #Testing if variable has characters and not numbers
  word = original.lower()
  first = word[0]
  if first in VOWELS:
    new_word = ''.join([word, PYG])                    #Word translated to pyg latin
    print new_word
  else:
    new_word = ''.join([word[1:], word[0], PYG])
    print new_word
else:
  print 'Empty'
```

Using `in` and `''.join()` is easier and more pythonic. `'\n'` just produces a newline before the input query.

As for your strange error... I expect your Mac was just throwing up something for one of the various problems with the code. EOF means "End of File." `raw_input` can throw the error but none of the calls you made should produce it normally. Alternatively, it could be because you are unintentionally using an older version of python that comes with your Mac and cannot accommodate some of those calls in the same way.

Anyway, not important. The code should work now.

Comment: Search for "python" and any of the code chunks I mention at the end for further details.